# Boolean evaluation between two lists is not working

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have a doubt about this evaluation, "old", which is a list of tuples should be evaluating False when evaluating with bp_list which is the same list of tuples, but with an item less. Thank you so much in advance.

```
while True: # game loop
    if dead_flag == True:
        pygame.time.wait(2000)
        dead_flag = False    
    MAINSURF.fill(BLACK)

    thePill.drawPills(p_inventary)
    oldpoints = points
    p_inventary, points = thePill.eatenPill(pac._x, pac._y, p_inventary)

    bigPill(*bp_list)
    #### This is the problematic part
    old = bp_list
    print ">>>", old
    bp_list = eatBig(bp_list, pac._x, pac._y)
    print "---",bp_list
    if (old != bp_list):
        print "they're different"
        print "##", old_bp_list
        print "##", bp_list
        score += 50

    if oldpoints != points:
        score = (basep - points) * 10


    """else: 
        print "old_bp_list ", old_bp_list
        print "bp_list ", bp_list    """     
    if p_inventary == []:
        break
```

Comment: What actually happens? What output do you get? What do all those other functions you're calling do?

Comment: Can you remove code and simplify functionality until the problem disappears, then take a good, hard look at the last version that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you expecting `old = bp_list` to turn `old` into a copy of `bp_list`? It doesn't. After that line, `old` and `bp_list` both refer to the same object, and any modifications to `bp_list` will show up on `old`.

Comment: thank you user 2357112! you are absolutely right. I just copied bp_list into a new reference(I don't know if my terms are correct) by doing this: old = bp_list[:] and voilá. You solved my problem, thank you. How can I mark your answer as helpful?

Comment: Since that turned out to be the problem, I've turned the comment into an answer that you can accept. You should see an outline of a check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
old = bp_list
```

This line doesn't turn `old` into a copy of `bp_list`. After this line, `old` and `bp_list` both refer to the same object, and any modifications to `bp_list` will show up on `old`.